# React JS: Filter an array by a string

Tags: arrays, string, reactjs, typescript, filter

it's me again, now with [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs).

I have a [json](/questions/tagged/json), inside it have two "rows", they are `Description` and `ubication`. I need to filter the array by `Description`.

How can I filter this? The description it's in text format for example `"Impact"` or `"Wiu wiu"`.

I know the function `filter()` of [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) have a numeric condition but no have a text condition or I haven't seen it been use for that.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No still you can do with Text as well,

```
let filtered = yourArray.filter(t=>t.Description ==='impact');
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
let mydata = {
  "ArrayBotones": [
    {
      "descripcion": "Impacto",
      "ubicacion": "sonidos/impacto.mp3"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Soy Fede",
      "ubicacion": "sonidos/holasoyfede.wav"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Wiu wiu",
      "ubicacion": "sonidos/wiuwiu.wav"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "3 carajos",
      "ubicacion": "sonidos/3carajos.wav"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Apurate Jose",
      "ubicacion": "sonidos/apuratejose.wav"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "No, no se",
      "ubicacion": "sonidos/nonose.wav"
    }
  ]
};

let result = mydata.ArrayBotones.filter(t=>t.descripcion === 'Impacto');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not works :/
    let Botones = ArrayBotones;
    console.log(Botones);
    let Botones2 = Botones.filter(botones=>Botones.descripcion ==='impact');
      console.log(Botones2);
    }

Comment: can you post your Botons array

Comment: The array come empty :C

Comment: dude ! if the array is empty how can you filter?

Comment: {
  "ArrayBotones":[
    {
      "descripcion": "Impacto",
      "ubicacion" : "sonidos/impacto.mp3"},
    {
      "descripcion": "Soy Fede",
      "ubicacion" : "sonidos/holasoyfede.wav"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Wiu wiu",
      "ubicacion" : "sonidos/wiuwiu.wav"

    },
    {
      "descripcion": "3 carajos",
      "ubicacion" : "sonidos/3carajos.wav"

    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Apurate Jose",
      "ubicacion" : "sonidos/apuratejose.wav"
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "No, no se",
      "ubicacion" : "sonidos/nonose.wav"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: The array is this. And when i use Filter(), Botones2 it's empty

Comment: check the demo above